# Creating and clearing rectangles in Flash CS5

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

I have an XML document that I am reading in and drawing a bunch of rectangles from the data that I get.  This bit of code is inserted in one frame.  Buttons are used to navigate through the frames. A button on the main screen takes you to the frame that draws the rectangles.  I have a Back button on the frame that draws the rectangles that takes you back to the main screen and that works fine but when I click Back, the rectangles that I drew still remain on the scene.  Is there anyway that I can erase all of the rectangles at once?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an array of type DisplayObject and add each object (Sprite, Movieclip) to it.

When you want to remove them, iterate through the array and remove the child:

```
// Adding object to the array
var objArray:Array;    // this could be a field member
objArray = [];

// ... navigate to your XML file and get each entry
// ... after you create an object, add it
if( objArray.indexOf(obj1) < 0 ) // Make sure it is not there so we do not add it twice
    objArray.push(obj1);


// Clearing...
for each (var obj1:DisplayObject in objArray)
{
    obj1.parent.removeChild(obj1);
}

// when done, clear the array
objArray = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove everything in the current frame:

```
function disposeFrameContent() : void
{
    while(numChildren)
        removeChildAt(0);
}

// run this code before you change frame
disposeFrameContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on how you draw the rectangles, if you use the graphics API, you could simply do:

```
    this.graphics.clear();
```

if you add DisplayObjects, do:

```
   while( this.numChildren > 0 )
      this.removeChildAt( 0 );
```

You can of course call these methods on any container MovieClip :

```
     //for instance...
     mc.graphics.clear(); 

     //or
     while( mc.numChildren > 0 )
         mc.removeChildAt( 0 );
```